# Mutex for ActiveRecord Model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My User model has a nasty method that should not be called simultaneously for two instances of the same record. I need to execute two http requests in a row and at the same time make sure that any other thread does not execute the same method for the same record at the same time.

```
class User
  ...
  def nasty_long_running_method
    // something nasty will happen if this method is called simultaneously
    // for two instances of the same record and the later one finishes http_request_1
    // before the first one finishes http_request_2.
    http_request_1 // Takes 1-3 seconds.
    http_request_2 // Takes 1-3 seconds.
    update_model
  end
end
```

For example this would break everything:

```
user = User.first
Thread.new { user.nasty_long_running_method }
Thread.new { user.nasty_long_running_method }
```

But this would be ok and it should be allowed:

```
user1 = User.find(1)
user2 = User.find(2)
Thread.new { user1.nasty_long_running_method }
Thread.new { user2.nasty_long_running_method }
```

What would be the best way to make sure the method is not called simultaneously for two instances of the same record?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a gem [Remote lock](https://github.com/HouseTrip/remote_lock) when searching for a solution for my problem. It is a mutex solution that uses Redis in the backend.

It:

- is accessible for all processes
- does not lock the database
- is in memory -> fast and no IO

The method looks like this now

```
def nasty
  $lock = RemoteLock.new(RemoteLock::Adapters::Redis.new(REDIS))
  $lock.synchronize("capi_lock_#{user_id}") do
    http_request_1
    http_request_2
    update_user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I would start with adding a mutex or semaphore. Read about mutex: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Mutex.html

```
class User

  ...
  def nasty
    @semaphore ||= Mutex.new

    @semaphore.synchronize {
      # only one thread at a time can enter this block...  
    }
  end
end
```

If your class is an `ActiveRecord` object you might want to use Rails' locking and database transactions. See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

```
def nasty
  User.transaction do
    lock!
    ...
    save!
  end
end
```

---

**Update:** You updated your question with more details. And it seems like my solutions do not really fit anymore. The first solutions does not work if you have multiple instances running. The second locks only the database row, it does not prevent multiple thread from entering the code block at the same time.

Therefore if would think about building a database based semaphore.

```
class Semaphore < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, :polymorphic => true

  def self.get_lock(item, identifier)
    # may raise invalid key exception from unique key contraints in db
    create(:item => item) rescue false
  end

  def release
    destroy
  end
end
```

The database should have an unique index covering the rows for the polymorphic association to item. That should protect multiple thread from getting a lock for the same item at the same time. Your method would look like this:

```
def nasty
  until semaphore
    semaphore = Semaphore.get_lock(user)
  end

  ...

  semaphore.release
end
```

There are a couple of problems to solve around this: How long do you want to wait to get the semaphore? What happens if the external http requests take ages? Do you need to store additional pieces of information (hostname, pid) to identifier what thread lock an item? You will need some kind of cleanup task the removes locks that still exist after a certain period of time or after restarting the server.

Furthermore I think it is a terrible idea to have something like this in a web server. At least you should move all that stuff into background jobs. What might solve your problem, if your app is small and needs just one background job to get everything done.

Comment: Locking the database record is the best plan here since most Rails deployments will have multiple processes running and a Mutex won't help you there.

Comment: Would these solutions be modified so that two instanses of different records could run the method simultaneously?

Comment: If I understand correctly the ActiveRecord lock! is only locking the database row, not the execution of the method. I guess I should update my question a bit to make it more understandable what I'm after.

Comment: I do agree, it is a terrible thing to have in a web server. But can't help, the API requires me to do it this way. I think your updated answer would do it, but I still like more the idea of storing the lock in Redis like in the gem I found (separate answer).

Comment: @Mike Sure Redis is also an option. The only point is to store it in a central repository.

Answer (score 2):

You state that this is an ActiveRecord model, in which case the usual approach would be to use a database lock on that record. No need for additional locking mechanisms as far as I can see.

Take a look at the short (one page) Rails Guides section on pessimistic locking - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pessimistic-locking

Basically you can get a lock on a single record or a whole table (if you were updating a lot of things)

In your case something like this should do the trick...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def nasty_long_running_method
    with_lock do
      // something nasty will happen if this method is called simultaneously
      // for two instances of the same record and the later one finishes http_request_1
      // before the first one finishes http_request_2.
      http_request_1 // Takes 1-3 seconds.
      http_request_2 // Takes 1-3 seconds.
      update_model
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this with a simple class https://gist.github.com/mmustala/c1d2ac21cf87d1acb762 and when I ran that test with 3 threads I got an ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError The third thread was not able to get a connection because the row was locked. Those http requests in the nasty method can sometimes take longer than the database timeout. So this will not be a solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a [gem](https://github.com/EByrdS/szymanskis_mutex) called `szymanskis_mutex`. It is a module that you can include in the class `User` and provides the method `mutual_exclusion(concern)` to provide the functionality you want.

It doesnt rely on databases and doesn't depend on how many processes want to enter the critical section at any given moment.

Note that if the class is initialized in different servers it will not work.

I may suite your needs if your app is small enough. Your code would look like this:

```
class User
  include SzymanskisMutex
  ...
  def nasty_long_running_method
    mutual_exclusion(:nasty_long) do
      http_request_1 // Takes 1-3 seconds.
      http_request_2 // Takes 1-3 seconds.
    end
    update_model
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest rethinking your architecture as this is not going to be scalable - imagine having multiple ruby processes, failing processes, timeouts etc. Also in-process locking and spawning threads is quite dangerous for application servers.

If you want to sleep well with production then try some async background processing framework for long running tasks with serial queue which will ensure order of running tasks. Just simple RabbitMQ or check this QA [Best practice for Rails App to run a long task in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508678/best-practice-for-rails-app-to-run-a-long-task-in-the-background) , eventually try DB but Optimistic Locking.

Comment: This is actually one part of a bigger background task. The task consist of multiple http requests into an external API. And there is this one part where I need to make sure that any other background task for the same user won't be able to run that nasty method at the same time.

Comment: In Java world I use ZooKeeper for distributed lock, here is an example of doing that in Ruby, http://ilyasterin.com/blog/2011/10/distributed-locking-made-easy.html . However I think you should use simple FIFO queue with one worker, or multiple queues/workers assigned by user id hashing. Then you get exclusiveness and parallelism.