# How to easily patch several ActiveRecord models against deadlocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, deadlock, database-deadlocks

So I maintain a Rails app with more than 150 database tables. And we are experiencing deadlocks at several locations.

After reading through this post https://hackernoon.com/troubleshooting-and-avoiding-deadlocks-mysql-rails-766913f3cfbc and understanding better the different situations. it seems one common pattern we have is due to unique index waiting for each others on concurrent lock.

So I am looking for a way to say in a model that it should not try to insert two at the time, since MySQL will lock the table. I want it as easy as.

```
class BingoCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  protect_table_locks
end
```

Which would use a Redis base lock, to wrap around the create operations

I already looked into this answer for ideas. [Mutex for ActiveRecord Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567108/mutex-for-activerecord-model)

I plan on posting my own answer when I have it.

Answer (score 1):

This is my draft implementation.
if there is enough interest, I will make it a gem

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module ActiveRecord
  module PersistenceRedisLock

    private

    def _create_record
      _lock_manager.lock(_locked_resource_id, _lock_duration) do |_lock_info|
        super
      end
    end

    def _locked_resource_id
      #TODO: make it a configurable option
      "PersistenceRedisLock#{self.class.table_name}"
    end

    def _lock_duration
      #TODO: make it a configurable option
      10.seconds # Maybe too long of a default, but this is a proof of concept for now
    end

    def _lock_manager
      @@_lock_manager ||= Redlock::Client.new [Ph::Redis.redis_url_for(:red_locks)]
    end
  end

  class Base
    def self.protect_table_locks
      self.prepend PersistenceRedisLock
    end
  end
end
```