# What is the Rails 6 Way to prevent multi-model logic from starting if it's already running for a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, database-locking

I have some complex business logic that runs when a controller action is hit. The logic performs various updates to many different tables/records associated with a user. However, the model method called by the controller is prone to running multiple times simultaneously if the route is hit fast enough in succession.

I want to make sure that the model method doesn't start if it's already in-process due to a previous request.

I've done some reading, and it sounds like database locking might be what I want, but it's not clear to me what *kind* of locking I want, or if I really want it for my scenario. I'm inexperienced in problems of this sort.

My logic doesn't just update one record, it updates a user record and also many different records associated with that user, across many tables. It doesn't seem correct to me to add a `lock_version` to every single table, but maybe that is normal? I *think* what I want is for the user and the user's relevant associated records to be frozen while this method is running, so I'm looking for the best way to achieve that.

What's the Rails Way to handle this with (hopefully) as little added complexity as possible? If locking is what I want, do I need to add a `lock_version` column to every single model that is updated as a result of this logic?

Comment: I don't think database-locking is what you want (I don't think you can lock specific records, you would end up locking tables for all users). I also don't think there's `a rails way` to do that, it would depend on each particular case but you are not giving a clear description of your system. I understand that you want to prevent a user hitting the same endpoint too quickly so maybe something like rack-attack's throttling helps you https://github.com/rack/rack-attack#throttling

Comment: This is another possiblity https://github.com/ClosureTree/with_advisory_lock

Comment: @JoelBlum This looks like it might be what I want, but I haven't gotten it to work. I've tried both `User.with_advisory_lock("finish_activity", transaction: true) do { my_method}` and `current_user.with_advisory_lock("finish_activity", transaction: true) do { my_method }`. I can still open 5 browser tabs and have duplicate completions if the code finishes in the same second. I am using postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) that is uniquely constrained by the user you are processing, either [with Ruby](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Mutex.html#method-i-lock) or [with a consistent database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(database_systems)) if you are building a distributed application.

Before an action begins processing, have it attempt to acquire a mutex. If it fails because another process already has it, halt.

Ensure that any process that has acquired a mutex releases it once it has stopped processing.

`lock_version` is important but it is merely a [database lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_locking). It ensures that an object cannot be saved if it has already been updated by another process.

If you are making [atomic commits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_commit), `lock_version` will work, but it is better to check for concurrent processing before you get to the commit-stage. A "process-level" lock such as this is something that you yourself have to implement.

Comment: Thanks, this mutex thing sounds like what I want. Where should I declare it though, and how can I associate it with my User model so that every user gets one? The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24567438/1196465 shows setting a `@semaphore` right in the User model, but it doesn't seem like wrapping the method contents in `@semaphore.synchronize {}` is enough to resolve the problem; I still get duplicate runs. I must be missing something.