# Ruby on Rails 4. Convert model to CSV and download it as a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails app and i need to provide button in UI which coverts required  set of model objects to CSV and downloads it to client PC. Can you help me to implement controller and UI Button?

Thx

EDITED

I've checked tutorial and I have some difference:

1. I need to call download method in my controller from JS because I should specify parameters which should be calculated in js
2. I want to make this download asynchronous to prevent page refresh

Is it doable?

Comment: Please search for a solution by yourself before you ask questions. I've only searched for `rails csv export` and the first result was a great Tutorial by [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel). Check it out and if you have any problems or questions then you are very welcomed to ask.

Comment: Thank you @Tobias, i ll try!

Comment: Okey, thx for tutorial, but i have some questions. Check my question please

Comment: Yes, it's "doable". You should try it. Read the help center here at SO to learn how to ask a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

yes, doable.
This list of links may help you

[stackoverflow-discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508678/best-practice-for-rails-app-to-run-a-long-task-in-the-background)

[railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel)

[video-tut](https://gorails.com/episodes/export-to-csv)

[blog](https://richonrails.com/articles/exporting-to-csv-using-ruby-on-rails-3-and-ruby-1-9)

[blog](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-csv-export/)